# How to make my Google Sheets document appear in my website with constant updates live?

Tags: javascript, html, google-sheets

So, while I was building my website, I faced a problem which it shows up in the website but it's not constantly updating whenever I make some changes. Sure it does change for like the first time changing the google sheet, but it takes for a while(around 7~20 minutes) to display another change.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<title> Track Service Hours </title>
<link rel="icon" href="Logo.jpeg" type="image/x-icon"/>
</head>
<body> 
    <p2><a href="Website.html">Go Back</a></p2>
    <!-- <script src="Refresh.js">
        Test
    </script> -->
  <iframe src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQnRhjEik9KrCt86pUZO4hkwAcKHpIwBA_3DnjfLobbWTJ_YSHYKipUlTA2SzZowpPaLpCV2V3FGKZs/pubhtml?gid=0&amp;single=true&amp;widget=true&amp;headers=false"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

There was a identical problem that's similar to mine. So, I tried to put window.setTime but it didn't work.

JS:
`window.setTimeout(1000);`

Is there anyway to make it "live" with constant updates?

Like I stated, I tried to search online and found a similar problem but didn't seem to work.  Plus, I wanted to make it live, which also didn't work out well either.

Error I am facing:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError ReferenceError: posObjs is not defined
    at switchToSheet (docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQnRhjEik9KrCt86pUZO4hkwAcKHpIwBA_3DnjfLobbWTJ_YSHYKipUlTA2SzZowpPaLpCV2V3FGKZs/pubhtml/sheet?headers=false&gid=0꞉47:967:62:11)
    at <anonymous> (docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQnRhjEik9KrCt86pUZO4hkwAcKHpIwBA_3DnjfLobbWTJ_YSHYKipUlTA2SzZowpPaLpCV2V3FGKZs/pubhtml/sheet?headers=false&gid=0꞉98:6920:98:6941)
```

[SpreadSheet Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/104QnCFEUt-g3ELrb3XcWEa0-r0yGoohwnlsC0jfatQk/edit#gid=0):

Comment: Can you provide your existing code with the error you have encountered? Also please provide a dummy sheet to work on with your desired output.

Comment: Edited to put Error code and sheet link.

Comment: `Edited to put Error code and sheet link.` Thank you for the error code and sheet link. However, the sheet doesn't include any scripts. So it isn't possible to identify when and how `posObjs` is referenced. Please create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)